# Faster loss convergence in the beginning leads to worse local minimum?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, convergence, overfitting

When doing feature selections, I've noticed that sometimes the same model converges faster with feature set A, than with feature set B, in the very beginning, but ends up with a worse loss later.

Here's a concrete example:

[image]

The model is a tree model and trained with lightgbm as a regression task, minimizing RMSE. Feature set A and B have the same number of features. Most features are similar and essentially capture the same information. Both models are trained for 100 rounds with the same hyper params and the plot showed the validation loss.

We could clearly see that the model trained on feature set B converged faster at first but did not outperform the other one in the end.

I'm thinking about how to interpret the result here: Should we choose feature set A as it indeed ended up with a better loss? Or maybe the faster convergence of feature set B actually indicated something important of those features?